# TabPane listener on selectedItemProperty not triggered if tab changed in code

Tags: javafx

I have the following listener:

```
tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Tab>() {

  @Override
  public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Tab> arg0, Tab arg1, Tab arg2) {
         System.out.println(arg2);
  }
});
```

But when I select a tab manually in the code, the listener isn't trigged? Is this a bug? Shouldn't this trigger the listener on the selectedItemProperty?

```
tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(tab);
```

Comment: This works fine for me. Can you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

1) Check if manual selecting is being triggered after the listener has been attached.

2) Check if the manual selected "tab" already is selected. If it is then no change listener will fire.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was an empty class file extending Tab.. I am sorry, should have remembered this, but many class files and I lost track.. Thanks for testing for me :)